# How to fill whole page with psframe in a0poster?

Tags: xetex, backgrounds, a0poster

Why doesn't this psframe include the right border of the poster? It colours just a square (see the output pdf picture). I'm compilating it with XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,final]{a0poster}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-grad}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\begin{document}
\psframe[fillstyle=gradient,framearc=0,linewidth=1mm,gradmidpoint=
0,gradbegin=green,gradend=yellow](0,0)(1.\textwidth,-1.\textheight)

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

And its doing the same thing when I use `psshadowbox` around a minipage. But if it suppose to be out of that functional square, than it moves into new line.

Comment: You're only letting it span `\textwidth` to `\textheight`, and there's an equal margin around the page border that will remain white. You can use something similar to [Shading over a single page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56716/5764) to shade with [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) using page nodes.

Comment: I don't get this output using `xelatex`. Perhaps you have outdated packages. See [Which package version am I using?](http://goo.gl/sBfU5X) and report back to us...

Comment: These black borders aren't a part of output, it's just from screenshot to see where the poster ends. I'm quite sure that I have the newest versions of packeges because I installed texlive-full, updated and upgraded whole computer yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps with `tikz` things are more human:

```
\documentclass[landscape,final]{a0poster}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \shadedraw[thick,inner color=green, outer color=yellow]([shift={(2.5,2.5)}]current page text 
     area.south west) rectangle ([shift={(2.5,2.5)}]current page text area.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So there's really nothing to put to psframe? Why is it than in the a0poster documentation: http://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-3/morales/morales.pdf (page 7)?

Comment: @Matej I really don't know much about `pstricks` :(