# Shifting radial shading arbitrarily

Tags: shading

I cannot find a solution for

1. Shift the circle to an origin as (0,0). As you can see in picture
   two, the picture is "distorted" (the same for circular sectors!)?.
   The placement should be arbitrarily on a chosen paper size.
2. Implement a definite paper size (want to choose A4 or A5) without
   margins. Perhaps via a standalone package? The current output in this
   respect is ok, but the paper dimensions are not. Note: the mention of
   paper width and height for the black background changes to a letter
   format (where does this come from?).

---

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usetikzlibrary{math,}


\definecolor{clr1}{RGB}{0.00,0.00,0.00}
\definecolor{clr2}{RGB}{40,0.00,40}%
\definecolor{clr3}{RGB}{60,0,60}%
\definecolor{clr4}{RGB}{80,0,80}% 
\definecolor{clr5}{RGB}{100,255,100}%
\definecolor{clr6}{RGB}{139,0,139}%
\tikzset{
%%
%%
shade radial/.code={%
\tikzset{%
        color four radial/.cd,% 
        #1,
        cfradial
       }%end second(!) tikzset
},%end code shade radial!
%
color four radial/.cd,%causes default path to be set to key(color four radial)  
                  shade radial color/.code n args={2} 
{\colorlet{cfradialcolor#1}{#2}},
                                           shade radial color={1}{black},
                                           shade radial color={2}{black},
                                           shade radial color={3}{white},
                                           shade radial color={4}{white},
                                           shade radial color={5}{purple},
                                           shade radial color={6}{purple},
%
cfradial/.style={/tikz/path picture={
                                 \xdef\radius{\radius}
                                 \pgfmathsetmacro{\rone}{0.65*\radius}
                                 \pgfmathsetmacro{\rtwo}{0.90*\radius}
                                 \pgfmathsetmacro{\rthree}{0.98*\radius}
                                 \pgfmathsetmacro{\rfour}{0.99*\radius}
                                 \pgfdeclareradialshading[cfradialcolor1,cfradialcolor2,cfradialcolor3,cfradialcolor4,cfradialcolor5,cfradialcolor6]
                                                         {cfradial}%shading name s. 3.01a, p. 1083
                                                         {\centerpoint}%center point 
                                                         {color(0pt)=(cfradialcolor1); %color specifications
                                                          color(\rone pt)=(cfradialcolor2);
                                                          color(\rtwo pt)=(cfradialcolor3);
                                                          color(\rthree pt)=(cfradialcolor4);
                                                          color(\rfour pt)=(cfradialcolor5);
                                                          color(\radius)=(cfradialcolor6) %
                                                         }
                                  \typeout{\radius,\rone,\rtwo}
                                  \pgfuseshading{cfradial}
                                 }%end path picture
             }%end style cfradial
%%
%%
}%%en
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%

\newdimen\circleradius

\tikzmath{
   \circleradius=14.0 cm;
}%end tikzmath

\coordinate (circleorig) at (-1cm,0cm);%%wrong if differs from (0,0)


\tikzset{
  recstyle/.style={minimum height=\paperheight,minimum width=\paperwidth,rectangle,draw=blue!50,fill=black!100,thick}
}
\node at (circleorig)  [recstyle]{background black};

\node [shape=circle, opacity=.5,
      inner sep=0cm,
      shade radial={
                    shade radial color={1}{clr1},
                    shade radial color={2}{clr2},
                    shade radial color={3}{clr3},
                    shade radial color={4}{clr4},
                    shade radial color={5}{clr5},
                    shade radial color={6}{clr6}
                   },%the one parameter of shade radial
      minimum size = \circleradius,
      font=\sffamily
     ] 
  (thecircle) at (circleorig) {do};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: no distortion on (0,0)]

[image]

I have tried bounding boxes and many more, but my faculties are too small to get the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have mixed up Latex and Tikz to solve the problem. The whole correct shaded picture is set into a minipage, which takes as much room as the picture, beside marginal borders, which can perhaps eliminated by Latex means if needed(new question).

The minipage will be moved left and right by values of hspace, up and down by vspace.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math,}


\definecolor{clr1}{RGB}{0.00,0.00,0.00}
\definecolor{clr2}{RGB}{40,0.00,40}%
\definecolor{clr3}{RGB}{60,0,60}%
\definecolor{clr4}{RGB}{80,0,80}%
\definecolor{clr5}{RGB}{100,255,100}%
\definecolor{clr6}{RGB}{139,0,139}%
\tikzset{
%%
%%
shade radial/.code={%
\tikzset{%
        color four radial/.cd,% 
        #1,
        cfradial
       }%end second(!) tikzset
},%end code shade radial!
%
color four radial/.cd,%causes default path to be set to key(color four radial)  
                  shade radial color/.code n args={2}{\colorlet{cfradialcolor#1}{#2}},
                                           shade radial color={1}{black},
                                           shade radial color={2}{black},
                                           shade radial color={3}{white},
                                           shade radial color={4}{white},
                                           shade radial color={5}{purple},
                                           shade radial color={6}{purple},
%
cfradial/.style={/tikz/path picture={
                                 \xdef\radius{\radius}
                                 \pgfmathsetmacro{\rone}{0.65*\radius}
                                 \pgfmathsetmacro{\rtwo}{0.90*\radius}
                                 \pgfmathsetmacro{\rthree}{0.98*\radius}
                                 \pgfmathsetmacro{\rfour}{0.99*\radius}
                                 \pgfdeclareradialshading[cfradialcolor1,cfradialcolor2,cfradialcolor3,cfradialcolor4,cfradialcolor5,cfradialcolor6]
                                                         {cfradial}%shading name s. 3.01a, p. 1083
                                                         {\centerpoint}%center point 
                                                         {color(0pt)=(cfradialcolor1); %color specifications
                                                          color(\rone pt)=(cfradialcolor2);
                                                          color(\rtwo pt)=(cfradialcolor3);
                                                          color(\rthree pt)=(cfradialcolor4);
                                                          color(\rfour pt)=(cfradialcolor5);
                                                          color(\radius)=(cfradialcolor6) %
                                                         }
                                  \typeout{\radius,\rone,\rtwo}
                                  \pgfuseshading{cfradial}
                                 }%end path picture
             }%end style cfradial
%%
%%
}%%end first tikzset

\begin{document}
%old code for black background replaced by this: 
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56716/shading-over-a-single-page?rq=1
%replace white and orange by black and the job is done
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \shade[left color=white,right color=orange!60]
      (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

%height above the picture. adding to vspace sets the circle lower
\vspace*{40mm}
%if zero, circle on most left place. adding to hspace shifts the circle to right side
\hspace*{50mm}
%\fbox{%just to see the minipage
\begin{minipage}{145mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}%

\newdimen\circleradius

\tikzmath{\circleradius=14.0 cm;}%end tikzmath

\coordinate (circleorig) at (0cm,0cm);

 \node [shape=circle, 
      inner sep=0cm,
      shade radial={
                    shade radial color={1}{clr1},
                    shade radial color={2}{clr2},
                    shade radial color={3}{clr3},
                    shade radial color={4}{clr4},
                    shade radial color={5}{clr5},
                    shade radial color={6}{clr6}
                   },%the one parameter of shade radial
      minimum size = \circleradius,
      font=\sffamily
     ] 
  (thecircle) at (circleorig) {do};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{minipage}
%}%end fbox
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]